# What is the difference between these two SQL Server connection strings

Tags: sql-server

When I use the following connection strings, the first one is working and the second is not working on my system. May I know the difference between these two connections strings?

```
DSN=ABCD;DATABASE=db1;UID=userid;PWD=passwd
```

and the second one

```
Data Source=ABCD;DATABASE=db1;UID=userid;PWD=passwd
```

Error thrown by second string

> [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

I am new to using SQL Server, so confused the difference between DSN and Data Source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many reasons as to why your second connection string is not working. You need to check [Why do I get error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"?](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb01039.html)

> The ODBC Driver Manager relies on the Driver attribute to know which
>   ODBC driver to load.

Comment: then what is this "Data Source" attribute in connection string, I have seen "Data Source" in many places while searching in google.I think DSN means "Data Source Name"

Comment: @user2753523:- `Data Source` is equivalent to `Server or
Address or 
Addr or 
Network Address` And yes you are correct DSN means Data Source name

Comment: where it will check for the "Data Source"? I mean how it will verify the valid data source

Comment: @user2753523:- You might have seen connection string with Data SOurce as `Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;`

Comment: I have many doubts now, but thanks for helping me in understanding the sql server connections strings

Comment: @user2753523:- You are welcome. And yes you can ask other questions as well when you are in doubt :)

Comment: Thank you very much:) One last question, if Data Source is "SERVER or Network Address" then what is SERVER attribute in connection string

Comment: @user2753523:- You can check this MSDN doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx I guess this will answer most of your queries. And yes to answer the Server attribute it is `The name or network address of the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. The port number can be specified after the server name\`

Answer (score 2):

Data source (in Data Source=ABCD) is not a valid connection keyword. See the connection properties [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568455(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In the first connection string DSN is an odbc DataSource name. If it works it means you have one configured.

In the second one Data Source is the sever name not the DSN.

For additional reference :

[DSN connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/)

[SQL Server connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)